# Finding out number of dropdown lists

Tags: c#, asp.net, drop-down-menu

I'm working on an application which list movies from a database. Except for general information (title, year etc) I list genres (one dropdown list per genre, which the user can choose genre from).

The thing is that I don't want the user to be able to delete a genre if only one exists (ie. a move should always have at least one genre), and here's where I need some help.

In the datasource I've created an event for Deleting, where I hope I could accomplish what I want. So, my idea is to find out if it only exists one dropdown list (ie. one genre), and if so, stop the event (deletion) from happening.

I would really appreciate some help here. Thanks in advance!

```
protected void MovieGenreDataSource_Deleting(object sender, ObjectDataSourceMethodEventArgs e) {

    DropDownList ddl = FindControl("GenreDropDownList") as DropDownList;

    if (// Number of genres = 1) {
        e.Cancel = true;
    }
}
```

Here's a screenshot from my app (in swedish), where "Redigera" = edit, "Ta bort" = Delete and "Lägg till" = "Add". I hope it makes my problem more clear.

[image]

Comment: I think that dropdowns are being added to the page dynamically. In this case FindControl() won't find anything :)

Comment: How are you adding your combo boxes in the first place? As an aside, from a UI  point of view, wouldn't a tick box list or a dual select box be more suitable here? It means a user can quickly select which genre's are applicable while seeing all genres, and it would also simplify your current problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is this what you need?

```
if (ddl.Items.Count <= 1) 
{
    e.Cancel = true;
}
```